# What is the difference between using substring's start index as 0 vs 1, other than the fact that the latter's length needs -1?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('BranchName|1001', 0, CHARINDEX('|', 'BranchName|1001'))
SELECT SUBSTRING('BranchName|1001', 1, CHARINDEX('|', 'BranchName|1001')-1)
```

Both the above return `BranchName`, as expected.

Official docs recommend start index starts with 1, but also explain what happens when we use start index as 0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments

What is the difference between using substring's start index as 0 vs 1 other than the fact that the latter's length needs to be subtracted by 1?

For example - does the 1st example miss out on anything that will be handled by 2nd example?

Comment: One difference if the case when CHARINDEX finds no match and returns zero. The first statement will quietly return an empty string, while the second will fail because the calculated length is -1, which is not a valid length for SUBSTRING. The start index can even be negative or greater than the length of the string. Start and length together define a range of positions, but only that portion that overlaps the given string is retrieved. For example, `SELECT SUBSTRING('abcde', -2, 5)` requests a range [-2 .. 2], but only [1..2] applies, yielding "ab".

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between using substring's start index as 0 vs 1 other than the fact that the latter's length needs to be subtracted by 1?

`start` parameter both 0 and 1 represent first char, but the formula of `substring` will affect the result, therefore why you need to calculate different numbers by `CHARINDEX` function.

The `start` parameter represents where the returned characters start, there is some logic on this parameter.

- The numbering is 1 based, meaning that the first character in the expression is 1
- If start is less than 1, the returned expression will begin at the first character that is specified in expression
- formula of `substring` function is `start + length- 1`

in your sample query, we can use the `formula` to prove those are the same result.

- first query (0 `start` + 11 `length`) - 1
- second query (1 `start` + 10 `length`) - 1

both queries are got 10 char number, `start` parameter both 0 and 1 represent first char, so you will get the result which starts at the first char to 10 char.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('BranchName|1001', 0, CHARINDEX('|', 'BranchName|1001')),CHARINDEX('|', 'BranchName|1001') len

|            | len |
|------------|-----|
| BranchName |  11 |

SELECT SUBSTRING('BranchName|1001', 1, CHARINDEX('|', 'BranchName|1001')-1),CHARINDEX('|', 'BranchName|1001')-1 len

|            | len |
|------------|-----|
| BranchName |  10 |
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/153880/1)**: